# How to implement scala type safety inside spark aggregation function

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, aggregate-functions

How do I implement type safety to the values being aggregated within the agg function? My goal is to have type checking before runtime. `$"event.zeroToSixty"`, for example won't be checked at compile time so I'd like to implement something that does.

`SomeMetadataExtracted` case class contains all types inside `event` column FYI

```
val currentDay = jobParameters.date.format(DateUtils.PartitionDateFormat)

val plusCar =
  MPHEventWrapper
    .loadMPHTable[SomeMetadataExtracted](
      plusTable,
      Seq(currentDay))

plusCar
  .groupByKey(row =>
    ( row.date,
      row.locale,
      row.carCode))
  .agg(
    count(when($"event.zeroToSixty" === Within5Seconds, 1 ) ).as[Long], <= need type checking here
    count(when( $"event.carLaunched" =!= Unknown, 1 ) ).as[Long], <= need type checking here
    count(when($"event.successfulLaunch" === true, 1)).as[Long])) <= need type checking here
  .map({
    case (
          (date, locale, carType),
          total_quick_cars,
          total_known_launches,
          total_successful_launches,

        ) =>
      carSpeedAggregate(
        date,
        carType,
        locale,
        total_quick_cars,
        total_known_launches,
        total_successful_launches,

      )
  })
```

**Updated Code** (Thanks Artem!!!) - new problem, code is super memory intensive

```
plusCar
    .groupByKey(row =>  (row.date,
        row.locale,
        row.carCode,
        ))
    .mapGroups {
        case ((date: String, locale:String, carCode: String), events: Iterator[EventWithCommonDimensions[EventCombiner[SomeMetadataExtracted, ANStep]]]) => {
          val newEvent = events.toTraversable

          val zeroToSixty = newEvent.count(e => { e.event.exists(_. e.zeroToSixty.getOrElse("UNKNOWN") =!= FollowUpUnknown )})
          val carLaunched = newEvent.count(e => { e.event.exists(_.carLaunched.get === Within5Seconds )})
          val successfulLaunch = newEvent.count(e => {e.event.exists(_.successfulLaunch == isTrue) })

          carSpeedAggregate(
            date,
            locale,
            deviceCode,
            taskName.get,
            total_quick_hangups.toLong,
            total_followup_calls.toLong,
            total_phone_calls.toLong,
            total_call_attempts.toLong
          )}
        }
```

Comment: Did you checked Datasets? Dataset provides type safety at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

agg is a function for untyped operations. Instead you can use, for example, combination of groupByKey and mapGroups.

```
# Suppose SomeMetadataExtracted has following fields
case class SomeMetadataExtracted(
    date: Timestamp, 
    locale: String, 
    carCode: String, 
    zeroToSixty: String,
    carLaunched: String,
    successfulLaunch: Boolean
    )

plusCar
  .as[SomeMetadataExtracted] //you have to make following import to do like this: import spark_session.implicits._
  .groupByKey((event: SomeMetadataExtracted) =>
    ( event.date,
      event.locale,
      event.carCode))
  .mapGroups{
      case ((date, locale, carCode), events: Iterator[SomeMetadataExtracted]) =>
    carSpeedAggregate(
        date,
        locale,
        carCode,
        events.count(e => e.zeroToSixty == Within5Seconds),
        events.count(e => e.carLaunched != Unknown),
        events.count(e => e.successfulLaunch)
    )}
```

Comment: One thing is that `date`, `locale` and `carCode` come from a different case class in the same row. If I we're to group by event in my first example, it would be `row.event`

Comment: It's not clear from your example. Can you share please type of plusCar? If it's a DataFrame share please its schema.

Comment: actually I got it to work! I'll post changes but before I do, it seems like only the first count function gets called. Any reason why?

Comment: ah, looks like its a TraversableOnce function. How would I make this Traversable?

Comment: I don't understand your problem now. Can your share updated code?
In my sample, events is an Iterator[SomeMetadataExtracted], so you can work with events like [regular scala iterator](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Iterator.html#count(p:A=%3EBoolean):Int)

Comment: Updated. but what I've neared is the Iterator has a TraversableOnce trait.